# Service Fabric and Identity Server 4

Tags: azure-service-fabric, identityserver4

I am new to identity server and have set it up on my development and it mostly works when using a single node. If I switch to 5 nodes it sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't.

I have the Authorize attribute on the controller which extends a base controller which have a function that gets the users role from the users claims.

```
protected string GetUserRole()
    {
        var roleClaim = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "role");

        if (roleClaim == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cant find role claim on: " + Request.Host.Host);
        }
        else
        {
            return roleClaim.Value;
        }
   }
```

What does happen when I make a authorized call (with a token in the header) is that roleClaim is null when it crashes. I then tried to make the call but this time unauthorized and got the same result.

This is the configuration for my api:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:19081/App/Identity",
            ScopeName = "api1",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });
```

Configuration for the identity server:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_contentRoot, "damienbodserver.pfx"), "");
        services.AddDeveloperIdentityServer()
            .SetSigningCredential(cert)
            .AddInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        services.AddMvc();
```

My client:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId = "myapi",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                ClientName = "My Beautiful Api",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowedScopes = {
                    "openid",
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> {
                    "*"
                },
                Enabled = true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And scope:

```
public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new List<Scope>
        {
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.ProfileAlwaysInclude,
            StandardScopes.EmailAlwaysInclude,
            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
            StandardScopes.RolesAlwaysInclude,
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "api1",
                DisplayName = "API 1",
                Description = "API 1 features and data",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                ScopeSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                    new ScopeClaim("role")
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I have tried to read the documentation but it seems like a lot is missing, so my question is first:

Why does the roleClaim exist only sometimes?

And Second:

Why doesn't Identity Server respond with a 401 status code when not authorized and I have [Authorize] on the controller?

Answer (score 0):

When idsrv lives on multiple nodes behind load balancer subsequent requests goes to different nodes and you need to provide consistency for them.

All instances should have at least IPersistedGrantStore (**AddPersistedGrantStore**) implemented for you DB.

I guess them also should have same cert (**AddSigningCredential**) and asp keystore (**AddDataProtection**). 
I suggest you to start with [distributed cache and data protection](https://github.com/SoCreate/service-fabric-data-protection). You may also temporary implement [IPersistedGrantStore like here](https://github.com/cleancodelabs/IdentityServer4.Contrib.Caching/blob/5e380c2cb0ca25e7d8e2f03cedbde84082653c38/src/IdentityServer4.Contrib.Caching.Redis/Stores/RedisCacheGrantStore.cs)